# How to create a widget for a tree view in Odoo 10?

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I have developed a widget for a form view:

```js
var core = require('web.core');
var form_common = require('web.form_common');

var MyWidget = form_common.FormWidget.extend(form_common.ReinitializeWidgetMixin, {
    template: 'MyWidgetTemplate',
    ...
});

core.form_custom_registry.add('my_widget', MyWidget);
```

I am calling it in the form view this way:

```
<widget type="my_widget"></widget>
```

It's working perfect. But, I need to use that widget in tree views. So I made the following modifications:

```js
var core = require('web.core');
var ListView = require('web.ListView');
var list_widget_registry = core.list_widget_registry;

var MyWidget = ListView.Column.extend({
    template: 'MyWidgetTemplate',
    ...
});

list_widget_registry.add('my_widget', MyWidget);
```

Afterwards I moved the line `<widget type="my_widget"></widget>` just after a field in a single tree view. But when I open that tree view, I get this JS error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Type is not a constructor*

Does anyone have any idea of why?

Comment: Interesting question, will dig on this and try to provide you an answer